# Change Google Groups email address, but address not listed

Tags: google-groups

I have changed my business email to another Google address and would like for my Google group messages to go to the new one. However, when I try to adjust the settings, it only lists the old email address. How do I get the new one to appear?

Comment: Which settings are you trying to adjust?

Answer (score 1):

## Answer

As you have a new Google account, you have to subscribe to the group with that Google account.

## References

[Find and join a group - Groups Help](https://support.google.com/groups/answer/1067205?hl=en&ref_topic=2458614)